# WebPack: Accessing Node Environment Variables in client code

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I'm working on a project using Webpack to package my client side JavaScript and CSS.  It launches a server so I can do hot reloading and other neat tricks.  So when I'm debugging my application, the webpack server is running at localhost:3000.  I am also using nodemon to launch another web server to host my API calls.  It obviously can't run on the same port, so I have to launch it on port 3002.

I have set a node environment variable that tells my api what port it should host on.  I need to somehow gain access to that same environment variable in my client script so my ajax calls know what port they need to be calling.

Before I started using webpack, I was hosting my api and my client code from the same port and I could just make api calls like this 'controller/action'.  Now that I have them hosted in essentially two different domains, I need to tell my api to call a fully qualified url including the port.  ie: 'host:port/controller/action'.  I understand that I'll also need to configure CORS on my API server as well.

When I push this to production, I will be hosting both client files and API calls from the same domain once again, so I will be able to continue making relative api calls 'controller/action'.  So I need to gain access to the environment variables from my client code so I can determine how to form the api calls in Dev verses in Production environments.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe a [webpack devServer proxy](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#proxy) would be worth pursuing.

```
devServer: {
...
  proxy: {
    '*/controller/*': {
      target: 'http://localhost:3002'
  }
}
```

The client would remain blissfully unaware of the differences between development/production.